# Formatting a string from a dictionary to use with cvs.DictReader to create dynamic SQL (KeyError: 'xxx')

Tags: python, csv

I am using Python (3.6) to write a script to load CSV files into a database. I want to provide the table schema as a dict (instead of hardcoding it).

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import os
import csv
from pathlib import Path

dirname='/path/to/folder'
dbname="{0}/mydata.db".format(dirname)

schema = {
            'tstamp': 'TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY',
            'col1':   'REAL',
            'col2':   'REAL',
            'col3':   'REAL',
            'col4':   'REAL',
            'col5':   'REAL',
            'col6':   'REAL'           
         }

tablename = 'foobar'
fieldnames = "({0})".format(", ".join(["'{0}'".format(x) for x in schema.keys()]) )
print("fieldnames: {0}".format(fieldnames))
schema_field_types = ", ".join(["{0} {1}".format(k,v) for k,v in schema.items()])
print("schema_field_types: {0}".format(schema_field_types))
create_table_ddl = "CREATE TABLE {0} ({1});".format(tablename, schema_field_types )
print("create_table_ddl: {0}".format(create_table_ddl))
values_string = ", ".join(['?' for i, x in enumerate(schema)])
print("values_string: {0}".format(values_string))
insert_table_sql = "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2});".format(tablename, schema_field_types, values_string)
print("insert_table_sql: {0}".format(insert_table_sql))

# if database does not exist, create it
if not os.path.isfile(dbname):
    print('mode: CREATE_DB')
    mode = CREATE_DB
    Path(dirname).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    Path(dbname).touch()    
else:
    print('mode: UPDATE_DB')
    mode = UPDATE_DB


con = sqlite3.connect(dbname, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cur = con.cursor()

if mode == CREATE_DB:
    cur.execute(create_table_ddl) 

with open(filename,'r') as fin: 
    # csv.DictReader uses first line in file for column headings by default
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    s = ", ".join(["{{{0}}}".format(k) for k in schema.keys()])
    print("s: {0}".format(s))
    row = next(dr)
    print(row)
    to_db = [(s.format(*i)) for i in dr]  # <- KeyError: tstamp
```

Why is a KeyError exception being raised - and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
fieldnames = "({0})".format(", ".join(["'{0}'".format(x) for x in schema.keys()]))
```

`csv.DictReader` expects a sequence of keys, for example

```
[k1, k2, k3...]
```

`fieldnames` is a *string*

```
"('tstamp', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6')"
```

so `DictReader` evaluates the fieldnames as

```
['(', "'", 't', 's', 't', 'a', 'm', 'p', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'o', 'l', '1', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'o', 'l', '2', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'o', 'l', '3', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'o', 'l', '4', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'o', 'l', '5', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'o', 'l', '6', "'", ')']
```

Using

```
fieldnames = schema.keys()
```

and changing

```
to_db = [(s.format(*i)) for i in dr]
```

to

```
to_db = [(s.format(**i)) for i in dr]
```

so each row is unpacked as a `dict` rather than a `list` will stop the error.

An observation: it may be easier to do what you are doing with `csv.reader` rather than `DictReader` - that way your columns will already be in a defined order, and you won't have to worry about the order of dictionary keys.

Comment: Thanks, the orderdict is now reading the csv data correctly, however, I still get the same KeyError, on the same line. I even tried changing the interpolated string into a tuple like this: `to_db = [(tuple(s.format(*i).split(','))) for i in dr]`. However, I still get a KeyError.